# How to combine child entities in to single _embedded array when using InheritanceType.JOINED from JPA and Spring Data Rest within Spring Boot?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Rest with Spring Boot 1.5.10.  I have three classes annotated with `@Entity`: `Message`, `AMessage`, and `BMessage` (Figure 2, 3, 4).  Classes `AMessage` and `BMessage` extend `Message` class (Figure 1).  I have one `MessageRepository` that is exposed via Spring Data Rest.  When I make a request to get all messages at `http://host:port/messages`, I get a response that contains two separate arrays under `_embedded` object (one for AMessage and one for BMessage) even though I am retrieving data from the `/messages` endpoint (Figure 5).  I only want to retrieve columns from the `Message` Entity.  How can this be achieved?

I have uploaded my code to [github.com](https://github.com/mawk09/spring-jpa-rest)

**Figure 1:** Hierarchy

```
           Message
              |
   ----------------------
   |                    |
AMessage             BMessage
```

**Figure 2:** Message Class (Parent)

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "MSG")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
public class Message {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String messageColumn1;
    @Column(name = "TYPE", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private String messageType;

    public String getMessageColumn1() {
        return messageColumn1;
    }

    public void setMessageColumn1(String messageColumn1) {
        this.messageColumn1 = messageColumn1;
    }

    public String getMessageType() {
        return messageType;
    }
}
```

**Figure 3:** AMessage Class (Child)

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "MSG_A")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class AMessage extends Message {

    private String messageAColumn1;

    public String getMessageAColumn1() {
        return messageAColumn1;
    }

    public void setMessageAColumn1(String messageAColumn1) {
        this.messageAColumn1 = messageAColumn1;
    }
}
```

**Figure 4:** BMessage Class (Child)

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "MSG_B")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class BMessage extends Message {

    private String messageBColumn1;

    public String getMessageBColumn1() {
        return messageBColumn1;
    }

    public void setMessageBColumn1(String messageBColumn1) {
        this.messageBColumn1 = messageBColumn1;
    }
}
```

**Figure 5:** Get messages response (aMessages and bMessages separated)
`http://localhost:8080/messages`

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "aMessages": [
      {
        "messageColumn1": "MColumn1",
        "messageType": "A",
        "messageAColumn1": "AColumn1",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/aMessage/1"
          },
          "aMessage": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/aMessage/1"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "bMessages": [
      {
        "messageColumn1": "MColumn1",
        "messageType": "B",
        "messageBColumn1": "BColumn1",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/bMessage/2"
          },
          "bMessage": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/bMessage/2"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/messages{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/messages"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 2,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved!  Created new repositories for `AMessage` and `BMessage`.  Annotated each repository with `@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "messages")`.  This caused the messages to be combined into a single array under the `_embedded` object, when performing a `GET` on `http://localhost:8080/messages`

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "messages": [
      {
        "messageColumn1": "MColumn1",
        "messageType": "A",
        "messageAColumn1": "AColumn1",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/aMessages/1"
          },
          "aMessage": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/aMessages/1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "messageColumn1": "MColumn1",
        "messageType": "B",
        "messageBColumn1": "BColumn1",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/bMessages/2"
          },
          "aMessages": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/bMessages/2"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/messages{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/messages"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 2,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```